# .aspx file doesn't work on IIS website

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have a big solution that contains a lot of .aspx file, basically it's a big sln file for my whole server

I wanted to add a website in my IIS server that contains inside a child directory within the root site folder, for example:

my-tools.com physical path is D:/MyWeb <-- Working well

I added a secondary sites, with no relation to the upper site called mysite which is like that:

mysite.my-tools.com which its path it D:/MyWeb/MySite/

If I try to reach mysite.my-tools.com/M_Index.aspx file it give me an error tells me it's not found, however, when I try to view a .jps file from the same directory (e.g mysite.my-tools.com/test.jpg) it returns just find.

it's important to tell that all the pages share the same solution, what do I do here and why it is not working? can anyone tell me?

thanks a lot

Comment: Which version of ASPNET and IIS are you using?

Comment: IIS 7, ASPNET Not sure, not my project, helping a friend of mine. I know it was compiled via VS 2008

Comment: try accessing it via my-tools.com/mysite/M_Index.aspx  FYI-A subfolder does not correspond to a subdomain by default

Comment: it does work that way, but I want it in the root folder of my subdirectory.

Comment: so you want it to be my-tools.com/M_Index.aspx?

Comment: mysite.my-tools.com/M_Index.aspx bro

Answer (score 0):

having the folder separated like you do is a step in the right direction.  next step is to configure IIS to point to that separate folder.  then you would need to create a DNS entry for your sub-domain at your DNS host. "subdomain.domain.com". You would be creating a new site, so you could use the same IP address, as long as you add the proper host headers for each site.

Comment: So why I'm able to view a jpg file inside my subdirectory?

Comment: I just added a website that points to my chosen physical path with a host that I've added with a subdirectory, but it seems to not found my .aspx files and show them

Comment: check in IIS, to make sure the version of .NET is 2.0, not 1.1

Comment: I just can't seem to find where to check it